# Covert ajax output into option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am getting html after ajax call and I want to change the output into option. I have select tags where I want to append these options

```
<div class="views-element-container">
  <div class="view view-contact-view-id-contact view-display-id-page_2 js-view-dom-id">      
     <div class="view-content">
        1009abc example    1008xyz example 12564abc cdfg &amp; TOT arrangement
     </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

now I want output:

```
<option value="1009">abc example </option>
<option value="1008">xyz example </option>
<option value="12564">abc cdfg &amp; TOT arrangement</option>
```

ajax excution: // msg[1].data contain the html

```
var contact_us_response = Drupal.ajax(elementSettings).execute();
contact_us_response.done(function(msg){
$(".ajax-progress.ajax-progress-fullscreen").remove();  
$('.contact_us_sub_cat_list').append('<option value="">Please Select</option>');
var content = $.trim($(msg[1].data).find('.view-content').text());
var arr = content.match(/(\d+)(\w+)\s+(\w+)/g);
  $.each(arr,function(index, value){
     var array = value.match(/\D+|\d+/g);
     $('.contact_us_sub_cat_list').append('<option value="'+array[0]+'">'+array[1]+'</option>');
  });       
});
```

Comment: To confirm, you want to take the *text* of `.view-content` and parse it into multiple `option` elements?   Is there any specific format/patter?   eg is it always 4numbers, 3letters, 1word?   Can you provide some other examples to determine the pattern?

Comment: @freedomn-m I added --- as a sepration betweed id and text

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant yes get the whole HTML as an output of the ajax call

Comment: @freedomn-m ok reverted to original. Yes I want to take the text of .view-content and parse it into multiple elements. No there is no any specific format/patter

Comment: If there's no pattern, then there's no way to "split" the text, eg "1009abc 1234example" - is that two options or one?   Why isn't "1009abc example    1008xyz example" a *single* option?

Comment: @RahulDravid If there's no pattern, then there's no way to "split" the text. you need to have a common pattern.

Comment: Hi as per @mplungjan Answer looks good to me as per his code snippet output  basically He check before and after numeric number. pattern [white space][numbers][text]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fragment and a regexp

```js
const str = `<div class="views-element-container"><div class="view view-contact-view-id-contact view-display-id-page_2 js-view-dom-id">      
  <div class="view-content">
      1009abc example    1008xyz example
 </div>  
 </div>
</div>`

const sel = document.querySelector("select");
const fragment = document.createElement("div");
fragment.innerHTML = str;

const re =  /(\d+)(\w+)\s+(\w+)/g;

let text = fragment.querySelector(".view-content").textContent.trim();

const matches = [...text.matchAll(re)];  // Convert matchAll iterator to Array

const optionsHTML = matches.map(match => {
  const [_, id, name, value] = match;
  const displayText = `${name} ${value}`;
  return `<option value="${id}">${displayText}</option>`;
}).join("");

sel.innerHTML += optionsHTML;
```

```html
<select>
<option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text always follows the pattern [white space][numbers][text], you could do this:

```js
let group = 0;

document.querySelector('select').innerHTML =
  document.querySelector('.view-content').textContent
    .split(/(\w[0-9]+)/gi) //(whitespace followed by numbers)(everything else)
    .slice(1) //get rid of the beggining whitespace
    .reduce((carry, value, index) => {
      if (index % 2 === 0) { carry[group] = []; }
      carry[group].push(value)
      if (index % 2 !== 0) { group++; }
      return carry;
    }, [])
    .map((items) =>  `<option value="${items[0]}">${items[1]}</option>`)
  .join('');
```

```html
 <div class="view-content">
    1009abc example    1008xyz example 12564abc cdfg &amp; TOT arrangement 404not found
 </div>
 <select></select>
```

Comment: How I can apply your code on ajax call return data? See the ajax call I made and in msg[1].data return the as html